# using animation and each for iterating animations

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
$(".container").animate({left:'120px'}, 6000).queue(function(next){
$(".child").css('display', 'none'); 
});
});
```

The above script animates a box and then hides it after the animation is completed.
The problem is that I have a set of identical boxes, and I want to animate each of them. I am trying to use .each to get it to work but so far it doesnt work at all. 
So to highlight my question once more**I want to animate a set of identical boxes one after the other in chronological order (html-vise, the one on top first, then the next), and then hide the box setting the css property and value. This works for one box, but not for several. I tried using .each, but no good news there.**

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
<div class="child"></div>
<div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you provide a http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Why are you using `.queue()`? The `.animate()` method gives you a callback option.

Comment: to make sure the css is applied at the end? it works! thats the important

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also do it this way !

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {  
$(".container").animate({left:'120px'}, 6000).queue(function(next){
var childs = $('.child'),
    i = 0;
(function() {
  $(childs[i++]).hide('slow',arguments.callee);
})();
});
});
</script>
```

Hope this can help you

Answer (score 2):

```
function queue(start) 
{
    var rest = [].splice.call(arguments, 1),
    promise = $.Deferred();

   if (start) 
   {
      $.when(start()).then(function () {
      queue.apply(window, rest);
                });
   } else {
        promise.resolve();
}
    return promise;
}





function animate()
{
    queue(function () {
        return $( ".child:first" ).animate({opacity: "show"}, "slow").delay(1500);
        }, function () {
        return $( ".child:first" ).animate({opacity: "hide"}, "slow");  
        }, function () {
        return $( ".child:second" ).animate({opacity: "show"}, "slow").delay(1500);
        }, function () {
        return $( ".child:second" ).animate({opacity: "hide"}, "slow"); 
    }});    
}
```

call animate when you want to fade in and out your divs